# Is there a way to process audio in realtime?

Tags: audio, microphone, audio-processing

If I record an audio segment with my [Yeti](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N1YPXW2) I can remove the white noise or noise from my fan with Audacity's [Noise Reduction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJOoI.png), and it works pretty well.

Is there any way to process this effect in real-time, for Skype, Teamspeak, etc.?

I tried to do a bit of research on the topic but nothing I typed into Google was anything near what I wanted.

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Quite easily in an app like Cubase, just add the plugin to the input channel; or on the o/p channel & listen to that. Routing after that would need to be done by another app - Audio Hijack or Soundflower on the Mac, to route to Skype's input. I have no idea if it can be done in Audacity, though.

Comment: just found this - http://superuser.com/questions/247327/deceptively-difficult-windows-audio-routing-problem

Comment: Could you clarify- what operating system are you using? I know that Ubuntu's PulseAudio has a [hidden noise reduction feature](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio). And if you use Jack, you can route the sound through an LVM plugin.

Comment: As you already would appear to be comfortable with the routing part, it might be good to re-word the question to make it clearer you are needing a solution for a realtime plugin rather than the additional routing required. It sounds like what you really need is a stand-alone plugin host - maybe along the lines of one of these - https://www.kvraudio.com/q.php?search=1&tg%5B%5D=133

Comment: In part, the answer posted already show that it isn't 100% clear. I'm not saying that's *not* what you're asking, just that most of the comments & the existing answer are *assuming* that routing is part of the question, so it might be better to clarify.

Comment: All I can say is that the longer this comment thread gets before we can actually focus on an answer, the more likely it is that a mod will stamp on it, move this thread to a chat-room & close the question as either 'unclear' or as a 'software recommendation'.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is an actual answer for this question that suits SuperUser, because it will require software, and as far as I know, all the software costs money. Due to that I have not enough experience with this to write an answer myself that I know will work.

Comment: @LPChip Even if it's paid software it's answer worthy, or if you know any off the top of your head here

Comment: Yeah, thats basically the point. I know Virtual Audio cable allows you to connect stuff together, which costs money. But then also a program that can be used for sure in this manner to apply a VST effect, I don't know.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, the latter is what I need. Bummer

Comment: I don't own Virtual Audio Cable, so I can't test it out with Xlutop Chainer, a program I bought that hosts VST effects, but in theory that should work. Xlutop Chainer however is no longer being developed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the [Stereo mix](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) feature in windows.

With stereo mix you can record everything that gets to output. Play the filtered sounds, and in Skype try to get input from Stereo mix.

Comment: Sorry but, I'm looking to process audio using an effect in real time. Not process one sample.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm not totally wrong the Audacity Noise Reduction works by using a noisy Part to make a Noise Profile which it then uses for the Filter. These Process can never bee used Realtime.

But there are other Applications which can do Noise Reduction Realtime i recommend you a look at NoiseGator https://sourceforge.net/projects/noisegator

For me it worked to just put some foam around my Headset Mic to remove most of the Noises. Since Foam is a lot cheaper than a Broadcaster Mic i would recommend you to give it a try.

If it doesn't work good enough with the Foam then it may be Time to start thinking about a Broadcaster Mic.

Comment: As an audio engineer, I can tell you that this is wrong. Of course you can sample a noise profile using a realtime stream and then use that data to process on the rest.

Comment: Also, that noisegator is not a noiseremover, but a gate only. Basically if you talk, there will still be noise, and if the noise is loud enough, near equally your voice, then this will not work at all.

Comment: @LPChip Well now we know it's possible :P